# ASP.NET MVC 4 Api Controller Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this method here and at the end of the method, I am looking to redirect the user. I have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    // Post Data to Database

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("/airportboard");
    return response;
}
```

but when I run this code, I get this error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
new Uri("/airportboard");
```

There isn't enough information for the `Uri` class to  accurately parse the path you gave it. You should pass something that at least has a protocol and domain in addition to the path, such as:

```
new Uri("http://example.com/airportboard");
```

There are several ways to construct this URL without needing to know much.